# Having trouble with an IF function- see below

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am creating a sheet that tracks exercise. At the bottom of the sheet, I have short list of calories burned with their corresponding activity. See the attached picture to see what the sheet looks like. I created a formula that I thought would automatically enter the calories burned in the "calories burned per hour" column, but it isn't working. Here is the formula:

=IF(F3="Weight Lifting", E238,IF(F3="Stretching",E240),IF(F3="Walking",e239) ,IF(F3="Elliptical",e241))

[Exercise sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5UTf.png)

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text.](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  For future reference, we prefer that you post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table) site if you want.  In general, you should include the output data you expect from your input data (clearly identifying which is which) and give a clear description of the computation you want Excel to do. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I guess what you have now is clear enough, although the bit about the short list of calories burned at the bottom of the sheet is confusing, since you don’t describe it. I guess cells `E238` through `E241` is the list? You might want to consider making that a table, where `D238` through `D241` are `Weight Lifting`, `Walking`, `Stretching`, and `Elliptical`, and then using `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` instead of a four-level nested `IF`.

Comment: I would recommend using a list or a table. Just the same idea you have already, but in a list. Then on the sheet you are designing you would use a VLOOKUP function. I see Scott above has recommended this too. It's more practical than nested IF's.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong. `IF` takes exactly three parameters, the IF, the THEN, and the ELSE. You produced a list of IF, THEN, IF, THEN.

By moving all parenthesis to the end, it will work. This basically puts each IF into the ELSE of the preceding IF:

`=IF(F3="Weight Lifting", E238,
  IF(F3="Stretching",E240,
  IF(F3="Walking",e239,
  IF(F3="Elliptical",e241))))`

(the returns are for ease of reading, you don't need them)

Note that there is no ELSE behind the last IF. That means if it doesn't match anything in your list, it will be 0. You can either add a default value if you wanted, for example if you want -1:
`=IF(F3="Weight Lifting", E238,
  IF(F3="Stretching",E240,
  IF(F3="Walking",e239,
  IF(F3="Elliptical",e241,-1))))`

(-1 makes no sense in the context, it is chosen for *illustration*)

Answer (score 0):

No error in formula Syntax wise it's Nested if, simply one ")" is missing, after 1st check, your Formula should be like

```
=IF(F3="Weight Lifting", E238) ,IF(F3="Stretching",E240),IF(F3="Walking",e239) ,IF(F3="Elliptical",e241), "".
```